# How to remove this Warning : Initialization of pointer of type 'id' to null from a constant boolean expression in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to remove the particular below warning error occured on iOS 8.

Initialization of pointer of type 'id' to null from a constant boolean expression in iOS 8.

```
 MainViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainviewController"];
 CustomNavigation *navigationController = [[CustomNavigation alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
 [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navigationController animated:NO];
 [navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
 [self.revealViewController revealToggle:NO];
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: @rmaddy [self.revealViewController revealToggle:NO];

Comment: Show the declaration for the `revealToggle:` method. What is the data type of the parameter?

Comment: - (IBAction)revealToggle:(id)sender{[self revealToggleAnimated:YES];}  - (void)revealToggleAnimated:(BOOL)animated

Comment: There's your problem. The `reviewToggle:` method doesn't take a `BOOL` parameter. It appears that you actually want to call `revealToggleAnimated:` and pass `NO` to that.